# Asynchronous tableView loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a class with methods that sends asynchronous requests to my database and then returns the objects into an array, I use blocks as a form of callbacks. I save the array in a singleton that can return it with a method.

The problem is I have almost no experience with tableViews, and I followed a tutorial that accesses data from an array and then creates tableView cells based on the number of objects in the array, and populates each cell's text label with the description of each object. Now I'm trying to make it work with my method and singleton, however the tableView loads before my singleton has recieved anything from the database, so how do I get through this problem?

Comment: Apparantelly I can't upvote you, however all 3 of the answers I got so far were helpful, many thanks as my problem is now resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `[tableView reloadData]` in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to bypass this. One is to use a delegate method from your singleton class to the viewcontroller that manages your tableview. When a delegate responds, reload your tableview [tableview reloadData]. You can use activity indicator to show the loading in process in between the time to load the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call 
- (void)reloadData
on your tableview once your data is done loading. You can achieve this in several ways, whereas using delegates is the most common way of doing it in iOS. You can create a delegate method which is called one your data is finished loading, and this method calls reloadData.

You can also trying calling reloadData as the last thing in your block.